Doesn't display counts from the database
I am writing a telegram bot on aiogram2 with sqlite3, I have a part of the code that should display the number of people, but it displays 0. Here is Database:
def count_people(self):
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users'").fetchone()
        if result:
            return result[0]

And the code that outputs these values:
async def stats(message : types.Message):
    if await check_sub(CHANNELS, message.from_user.id):
        people = db.count_people
        await message.answer(f'People in bot:{people}  ', reply_markup=stats_kb)
    else:
        await message.answer(NOT_SUB_MESSAGE, reply_markup=showChannels())

Table in db:

I tried all tutorials and all similar problems in forums

Is count_people returning a number or None?

count_people returns 0

Not sure if it's the problem, but none of the single quotes in the SQL statement are required.

Try SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users. Unless there can be null user IDs that you don't want to count, there's no need to specify the column name.
